How to convert 32 length string (num type) into primitive long
as per que. I've to convert long decimal number into binary number, then I need to convert it into it's complement. But number should be 32 bit long. i.e. I've to write extra 0's in front of complement num. I did everything. Lastly complement num. is in string and I've to convert it into long primitive.
public static long flippingBits(long n) {
  String s = Long.toBinaryString(n); //binary of long n

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //to store complement of n.
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(flip(s.charAt(i))); //each char of string s is send to method flip to get it's binary
        }

        int b = 32 - s.chars().toArray().length; //to know how many extra 1's are need to be insert in front               of complement string.

        String s1= sb.toString(); 
        for (int i =0; i<b; i++)  s1 ="1"+s1; //direct insert 1 bcz complement of 0 
        long res = Long.valueOf(s1); //error causing statement
        return res;
    }
        static char flip(char c) //to make complement of binary. '~' operator doesn't work
            {
                return (c == '0') ? '1' : '0';
            }

I've used Long.valueOf(String s);  Long.parseLong(String s); but both methods are giving NumberFormatException. I think max value of primitive long in java is 19 digit long and my requirement is 32 digit long string conversion that's why it raises error but not sure.
I'm expecting-
eg n= 9; //decimal
9 = 1001; //binary
 We're working with 32 bits, so: 9 = 00000000000000000000000000001001;
11111111111111111111111111110110 //complement of above binary. I got everything fine up to this.
= 4294967286 //decimal 
return 4294967286 ;


Long.parseLong("11111111111111111111111111110110", 2) -- $2 ==> 4294967286

You are trying to parse a binary number as a decimal number.  You need to specify the radix of the input.
String s1 = sb.toString();
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
     s1 = "1" + s1; // direct insert 1 bcz complement of 0
long res = Long.valueOf(s1,2); // <-- radix is 2.

Note that you can also just flip the bits using bitwise operators and avoid strings.

use ~ to flip (complement) the bits.
use & to AND the bits and preserve the low order 32 bits by masking the low
order 32 bits with all ones.

public static long flippingBits(long n) {
        return ~n&0xFFFF_FFFFL;
}

If you are required to "compute" it yourself via iteration, you could also do something like the following:

using a for loop check the first 32 bits.  The value is used as the number of bits to shift 1 to test for a set bit.
if you AND ( & ) that value with n, the result will be non-zero if set and 0 if not set.
if zero, set that bit using an OR ( | ) operator, otherwise OR it with 0.

public static long flippingBits(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        long bitPos = 1L << i;
        sum |= (n & bitPos) == 0 ? bitPos : 0;
    }
    return sum;
}

